# IBM MQ MQCONN from host to Docker container

Tags: c, docker, ibm-mq

Trying to connect from a C application running as an IBM MQ client on a host to an MQ server running as a docker container.

The client code taken from an IBM example is provided below.
The questions is which protocol is used when MQCONN is called as no IP/port is provided? I can only guess it is some kind of an IPC.
For this reason I'm running the docker container with --ipc="host" option, but it still fails with CompCode=2, Reason=2058

```
#include <cmqc.h>
⋮
static char Parm1[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] ;
⋮
int  main(int argc, char *argv[] )
   {
   /*                                                    */
   /*     Variables for MQ calls                         */
   /*                                                    */
   MQHCONN Hconn;      /* Connection handle              */
   MQLONG  CompCode;   /* Completion code                */
   MQLONG  Reason;     /* Qualifying reason              */
⋮
   /* Copy the queue manager name, passed in the         */
   /* parm field, to Parm1                               */
   strncpy(Parm1,argv[1],MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH);
⋮
   /*                                                    */
   /* Connect to the specified queue manager.            */
   /*   Test the output of the connect call.  If the     */
   /*   call fails, print an error message showing the   */
   /*   completion code and reason code, then leave the  */
   /*   program.                                         */
   /*                                                    */
   MQCONN(Parm1,
          &Hconn,
          &CompCode,
          &Reason);
   if ((CompCode != MQCC_OK) | (Reason != MQRC_NONE))
      {
      sprintf(pBuff, MESSAGE_4_E,
              ERROR_IN_MQCONN, CompCode, Reason);
      PrintLine(pBuff);
      RetCode = CSQ4_ERROR;
      goto AbnormalExit2;
      }
⋮
   }
```

Comment: If the client app is running local to the same server as the queue manager it can connect in "binding" mode using only shared memory.  If the MQ client is not local an you call MQCONN with a queue manager name it will attempt to find out how to connect to it via a few different methods including environment variables or mqclient.ini.  If none of these are found then you normally get the 2058 (MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR) error.  With docker you would need to know the external IP and port to connect to your queue manager.

Comment: Many thanks!. in my case it is local, the C code is running on the host and the queue manager is running inside a container. I think is should be using the shared memory approach you mention, not sure if it is possible with Docker.

Comment: I think that the C code would need to run in the container to be able to communicate to the queue manager with the shared memory approach.

Comment: What I ended up going is to set the environment variable MQSERVER to point to tcp/1414 on localhost where the Docker container is listening and it works.
Your first comment pointed me at the right direction.
```bash
export MQSERVER=DEV.APP.SVRCONN/TCP/'localhost(1414)'
```

Comment: Note that using that setting with MQCONN means the queue manager is open to anyone that can get to port 1414 of your docker container.  MQCONN can not pass username/password authentication and MQSERVER does not allow for anything else that would provide any form of authentication.  If this is only a test system that may be OK, but then you need to figure out how to do it with authentication on the prod system someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program will be running on the same server as the queue manager then it is best to link it with 'mqm.lib' (bindings mode) rather than 'mqic.lib' (client mode).

In the [MQ KnowLedge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q028490_.htm), there are examples on how to compile and link your C program.  The examples are listed as: 'C client application' (client mode) and 'C server application' (bindings mode).

If in the future, your C program needs to connect to a remote queue manager then you need to link it for 'client mode'.

To configure your C program to handle proper MQ security, change the MQCONN API call to MQCONNX API call.

i.e.

```
MQCNO   cno   = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};
MQCD    cd    = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};
MQCSP   csp = {MQCSP_DEFAULT};

strncpy(cd.ConnectionName, hostname, MQ_CONN_NAME_LENGTH);
strncpy(cd.ChannelName, channelName, MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);

csp.AuthenticationType = MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD;

csp.CSPUserIdPtr = &myUserId;
csp.CSPUserIdOffset = 0;
csp.CSPUserIdLength = strlen(myUserId);

csp.CSPPasswordPtr = &myPassword;
csp.CSPPasswordOffset = 0;
csp.CSPPasswordLength = strlen(myPassword);

cno.cdPtr = &cd;
cno.Version = MQCNO_CURRENT_VERSION;
cno.SecurityParmsPtr = &csp;
cno.SecurityParmsOffset = 0;

MQCONNX(QMgrName, &cno, &Hcon, &CompCode, &Reason);
```

A few years ago, I wrote a blog posting called: [MQ API Verbs that IBM Forgot!!](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4309).  I created wraps for MQCONN and MQCONNX that will allow the program to pass UserId & Password for MQCONN and MQCONNX API calls.  You may find it easier to simply use the wrappers.

Comment: With 7.1 and later if you stick to the mqm lib then the app can connect binding or client without any code changes, if you use mqic it can only connect client.

Comment: @JoshMc true but I find newbies find the concept confusing.